# Stop for loop before empty cell

Tags: excel, loops, powershell

```
for ($i = 1; $i -le $somenumberofusedcellsinthecolumn; $i++) {
     $cell = $ws.Cells.Item($i, 1)
     $value = $cell.Value2 -as [string]
     write-host $value  
}
```

I want my for loop to terminate when the next cell in the column is empty. I don't know though how to get set the ending point for my loop though since people could add more data to the excel sheet.

I've seen online that some people have used the following as their ending point for the loop, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
   $rows = $ws.range("c2").currentregion.rows.count
```

Comment: I'm sorry, are you trying to loop through all of the used cells? Or just a certain section (such as A2:D40 or something), and stop at the last used cell?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Sorry, Yeah so basically just loop through one column of used cells and count how many there are so I can stop my loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we could loop through cells checking for the value of the next cell and what not, what I think will better server your purposes is to just get the values directly from the column that you want and store it in an array. Let's assume that you are interested in the data in Column B. We would select the Columns property of your worksheet, skip 1 column, and select the first next column (skip A, and get the values from B). Then we just expand Value2, which is already an array of the values of all the used cells in that column, and it feeds you all the data you're looking for. Try this out and see how you like it:

```
$Data = $ws.Columns | Select -Skip 1 -First 1 | Select -Expand Value2
```

Now `$Data` is an array containing all of the used cells from Column B. Want Column C? Change it to `-Skip 2`. Or if you want Column A you just remove the `-Skip` entirely. Once you have your data you can output it to the screen, parse it as needed, save it to a file, or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a while loop and exit once an empty cell is reached.

```
$i=1
$nextValue = $true
while ($nextValue -eq $true) {
     $cell = $ws.Cells.Item($i, 1)
     $value = $cell.Value2 -as [string]
     write-host $value
     if ($ws.Cells.Item($i+1, 1).Value() -eq $Null) {
         $nextValue = $false
     }
     $i++
}
```

Does that work for your purposes?